# BeautifulSoup find a div tag by the text inside

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have this html format

```
<tr>
  <th>
    <div>USING THIS TEXT</div>
  </th>
  <td>
    <div class="plainlist">
      <ul>
        <li>
           "GET THIS TEXT HERE"
           <span> 
             " ("
             <span class="bday"> "AND GET THIS TEXT HERE"
             ")"
           </span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I have figured out how to get access to an unordered list using find and id, but am unsure of how to do it when the div I want doesn't have an id, but only text which I can use.

If there were an id, then the python code would be

```
test = soup.find(id="[SOME_ID]")
        if test is not None:
            ul = cast.find_next('ul')
            for li in ul.findAll('li'):
                if(li is not None):
                    print(li.text)
```

But I'm not sure how to get that "test" value with knowing just the text inside the div, not the id.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Post your Python code, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import re module to find tag by text.try this let me know if this work.

```
import bs4
import re
html_doc="""<html><tr>
  <th>
    <div>USING THIS TEXT</div>
  </th>
  <td>
    <div class="plainlist">
      <ul>
        <li>
           "GET THIS TEXT HERE"
           <span>
             " ("
             <span class="bday"> "AND GET THIS TEXT HERE"
             ")"
           </span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr></html>"""
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')
test=soup.find('div' , text=re.compile("USING THIS TEXT"))
if test is not None:
            ul = test.find_next('ul')
            for li in ul.findAll('li'):
                if(li is not None):
                    print(li.text)
```

Output :

```
"GET THIS TEXT HERE"

             " ("
              "AND GET THIS TEXT HERE"
             ")"
```

Comment: The 'text' argument to find()-type methods is deprecated. Use 'string' instead.